# Any significance of inviting Roland to tell a story?

Tags: the-dark-tower

I was reading "The Gunslinger" and this sentence caught my attention.

> “**I guess you won’t feel right about it unless I invite you**,” Brown said, “**and so I do. Will you tell me about Tull?**”
>
> The gunslinger was surprised to find that this time the words were there. He began to speak in flat bursts that slowly spread into an even, slightly toneless narrative.
>
> ***The Gunslinger, Chapter 4***

Before this, when Ronald felt like sharing his story, the words did not come to him.

> The gunslinger searched for words to begin and found none. “I have to pass water,” he said.
>
> ***The Gunslinger, Chapter 4***

It looks like Brown knew, so he invited Roland to tell his story. Is this explained anywhere?

Comment: I don't think Brown knew, just that Roland had already dropped the fact that the town was dead.  This just looks like Brown trying to get Roland to talk about it, like you would gently prod anyone who's been through a trauma that might need some talk.